# AngularJs Modal Pass Values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to pass a value to the Popup Controller, but is only passing if i insert this "havePermissions" in the controller but gives this error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=havePermissionsProvider (Unknown provider: havePermissionsProvider)

if i remove this "havePermissions, i dont have the error, but dont pass the value to the modal controller (is undefined the value)

Modal Open

```
$scope.open = function (size) {
        var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
        modalScope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Views/Common/participants.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlPartic',
            size: size,
            scope: modalScope,
            resolve: {
                havePermissions: function () {
                    return $scope.havePermissions;
                }
            }
        });
        modalScope.modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        });
    };
```

Modal Controller

```
angular.module("participants.controller", ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller("ModalInstanceCtrlPartic", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", 
"$routeParams", "UserService","havePermissions","logger",
            function ($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, UserService, 
havePermissions,logger) {

            var page = $location.path().split('/')[1];
            $scope.havePermissions = havePermissions;

            $scope.ID_Event = page == "events" ? $routeParams.eventId : null;
            $scope.ID_UserGroup = page == "groups" ? $routeParams.groupId : null;
            $scope.page = page;

            $scope.model = {};

            UserService.GetParticipants($routeParams.groupId, $routeParams.eventId).then(function (response) {
                $scope.model = response.data;
            }, function (e) {
                logger.logError("Ocorreu um erro, tente novamente.!");
            });

            $scope.emailList = [];

            $scope.ok = function (list) {
                //envia email
                $scope.modalInstance.close('');
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $scope.modalInstance.close('');
            };

        }]);
```

Comment: please post whole angular code

Comment: Updated with the controller code

Comment: where is the `havePermissions` ?

Comment: is the the "$scope.open / resolve" is a variable i want to pass to the modal controller.

Comment: ok please post the `havePermissions` provider ?

Comment: @Luis  try scope: $scope inside modal.open

Comment: @K.Toress havePermissons provider has already declared inside modal declaration resolve

Comment: yeah ok then u cant inject that in to the controller like u do. you can inject the provider like `factory`,`service` in to controller. but you cannot inject `havePermission` since its not a provider

Comment: @K.Toress why can you explain it?

Comment: no isn't a provider. What i wanna explain is if i type the havePermission there, the value is pass over the controller, if i removed the value is undefined. for example here http://plnkr.co/edit/7uigdg6Gu6yF1WfPdUbU they pass the Items Value. but i dont know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Luis have you tried to scope: $scope inside modal.open? i believe scope is messing with controller

Comment: can you please create a plunker of your problem that would be easy.

Comment: modalScope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Views/Common/participants.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlPartic',
            size: size,
            scope: $scope, //or remove this line
            resolve: {
                havePermissions: function () {
                    return $scope.havePermissions;
                }
            }
        });

Comment: @Luis  1st place do you really want isolated scope inside pop up?

Comment: I have the modalScope = $rootScope.$new();, because was the only way to have the modalInstance on my controller.

Comment: @Luis  try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$modal.open` method should not go inside the newly created scope.
Keep var modalInstance = $modal.open({//init code})

Modal code will be changed as follows.

```
$scope.open = function (size) {
        var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Views/Common/participants.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlPartic',
            size: size,
            scope: modalScope ,
            resolve: {
                havePermissions: function () {
                    return $scope.havePermissions;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
        });
    };
```

Here is updated **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FkW8sxhrwe7P1qN98arT?p=preview)** not exactly the same.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: i have the scope that way, because i want to have the modalinstance in my code. i follow this example http://uithought.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/use-the-same-controller-for-modal-and-non-modal-template-in-angular-ui-bootstrap/